# Get data from API using Axios and MobX in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, mobx

I learning Axios with MobX in React Native in JS. I'm trying get data from API using that technology and transfer to view, but I passing only empty array or undefined

Firstly I have a file when I calling to API by Axios

I think in this place is error but I don't know where

```
import API from "./api";

export function exampleGroupsAPI() {

  return API.get('/example-groups').then(response => response.data)
}
```

The next file I have store for my data

```
import {makeAutoObservable, runInAction} from 'mobx';
import {exampleGroupsAPI} from '../api/agent';

export default class ExampleGroupsStore {
  exampleGroups = [];

  loadingInitial = false;

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  setLoadingInitial = state => {
    runInAction(() => {
      this.loadingInitial = state;
    });
  };

  loadExampleGroups = async () => {
    const result = await exampleGroupsAPI();
    runInAction(() => {
      this.exampleGroups = result.data;
})

  };
}
```

and that component is the place when I trying show the data, but this console.log show only undefined or empty array

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {observer} from 'mobx-react-lite';
import {useExampleGroupsStore} from '../../app/stores/hooks';

const ExampleGroupsList = () => {
const { exampleGroups, loadExampleGroups} = useExampleGroupsStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    loadExampleGroups();
  }, [loadExampleGroups]);

  console.log(exampleGroups)
  return (
<Text>
  TEST
</Text>

  );
};

export default observer(ExampleGroupsList);
```

The last one is file when I export store

````
import {StoreContext} from './storeProvider';
export function useExampleGroupsStore() {
  const store = useContext(StoreContext);

  return store.ExampleGroupsStore;
}```
````

Comment: How does `useExampleGroupsStore` look like? And have you tried to console.log data here `this.exampleGroups = result.data` for example, is it there at that point or not?

Comment: I was added useExampleGroupsStore in up 

I was tried console.log in `this.exampleGroups = result.data` but it just nothing.

Comment: If `result.data` is undefined then what is just `result` at that point?

Comment: wow, when I tried just `result` I have console log with all data in array

Comment: Ok, good, if it's solved and it was just a typo you can close the question!